# Multiple inner joins or multiple queries?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to display a table that lists a game's title, developer(s) and publisher(s). Each game can have multiple developers and publishers. From the below diagram, is it possible to get all this information through one query using inner joins or will I have to make multiple database transactions?

[image]

As it stands I have been able to obtain a game's developer (singular) but I'm not sure how to grab multiple developers as well as multiple publishers in the one query. This is my query so far:

```
SELECT games.id, games.title, companies.id, companies.name
INNER JOIN game_developer ON game_developer.games_id = games.id
INNER JOIN companies ON companies.id = game_developer.companies_id
GROUP BY games.title
ORDER BY games.title
LIMIT 50
```

The final product should look something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT` to get all the names:

```
SELECT games.id, games.title, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT dc.name) AS developers,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT pc.name) AS publishers
INNER JOIN game_developer ON game_developer.games_id = games.id
INNER JOIN companies AS dc ON dc.id = game_developer.companies_id
INNER JOIN game_publisher AS gp ON gp.games_id = games.id
INNER JOIN companies AS dp ON dp.id = gp.companies_id
GROUP BY games.id
ORDER BY games.title
LIMIT 50
```

You need to use `DISTINCT` because joining with both publishers and developers will generate a cross product with lots of duplicates.